# Disable A Button When asp:TextBox Empty & no asp:RadioButton Is Selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an `asp.net` webform and i want my submit button to be disabled if my `asp:TextBox` is empty and also no selection has been made for my `asp:RadioButton`.

Currently i have the following for my field but i dont know how i can join this for the radio buttons

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $("#MainContent_btnRemoveUser").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#MainContent_btnAddUser").prop('disabled', true);
        });

        // Disables 'Remove' button unless all fields popluted
        $("#MainContent_txtRemoveUser").on("change", function ()
        {
            if ($('#MainContent_txtUsername').val())
            {
                $("#MainContent_btnRemoveUser").prop('disabled', false);
            }
            else
            {
                $("#MainContent_btnRemoveUser").prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });
```

**HTML**

```
        <div class="form-group">        
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtRemoveUser" CssClass="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-3 control-label">Enter Name To Be Removed</asp:Label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtRemoveUser" CssClass="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-3 control-label">
                <b>Request For</b>
            </asp:Label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbRemoveYourself" GroupName="RemoveRequestFor" /> Myself
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbRemoveOtherUser" GroupName="RemoveRequestFor" /> Other user
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-8 col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 0px">
                <asp:Button ID="btnRemoveUser" runat="server" Text="Remove From The List" CssClass="btn btn-danger" ToolTip="Click to remove the specified user from the payday lunch list." />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go! a new function has been added to disable the button and will be called on blur for text box and on change for radio buttons.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="form-group">        
                <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtRemoveUser" CssClass="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-3 control-label">Enter Name To Be Removed</asp:Label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtRemoveUser" CssClass="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-3 control-label">
                    <b>Request For</b>
                </asp:Label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbRemoveYourself" GroupName="RemoveRequestFor" /> Myself
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbRemoveOtherUser" GroupName="RemoveRequestFor" /> Other user
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-8 col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 0px">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnRemoveUser" runat="server" Text="Remove From The List" CssClass="btn btn-danger" ToolTip="Click to remove the specified user from the payday lunch list." />
                </div>
            </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#MainContent_btnRemoveUser").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#MainContent_btnAddUser").prop('disabled', true);
        });

        $("#MainContent_txtRemoveUser").on("blur", function () {
            disableButton();
        });

        $("#MainContent_rbRemoveYourself").change(function () {
            disableButton();
        });

        $("#MainContent_rbRemoveOtherUser").change(function () {
            disableButton();
        });

        // Disables 'Remove' button unless all fields popluted
        function disableButton() {

            var isRbRemoveSelfChecked = $("#MainContent_rbRemoveYourself").is(':checked')

            var isRbRemoveOtherChecked = $("#MainContent_rbRemoveOtherUser").is(':checked')

            if ($('#MainContent_txtRemoveUser').val() != '' && (isRbRemoveSelfChecked || isRbRemoveOtherChecked)) {
                $("#MainContent_btnRemoveUser").prop('disabled', false);
            }
            else {
                $("#MainContent_btnRemoveUser").prop('disabled', true);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: All that happens is that ass soon as I entered text into the 'txtRemoveUser' field, the button becomes enabled without me having to select a radio button

Comment: Change the condition from OR to AND. Change the event as well to blur instead of change

Comment: I've modified the answer. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Now it doesn't become enabled when I populate the field and select my radio button

Comment: I have added breakpoints to the `vars` and the `IF` and it hits it when I tab or click out of field but not when I select my radio button

Comment: Answer has been updated. The logic to disable the button has been moved to a separate function and called three time. This should work. HALA MADRID :p

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the expected result:-

```
$('input[name="RemoveRequestFor"]').change(function () {
    if($("#MainContent_txtUsername").val().trim() != "")
         $("#MainContent_btnAddUser").prop('disabled', false);
});

$("#MainContent_txtUsername").blur(function () {
    if($('input[name="RemoveRequestFor"]:checked').length > 0)
         $("#MainContent_btnAddUser").prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Also, you can use `keyup` function instead of `blur` to make your form more responsive.

Comment: This so much cleaner than my own answer and the result is the same!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `if ($('#MainContent_txtUsername').val())` with
 `if ($('#MainContent_txtUsername').val() != '')`

For radio button, don't check any condition on `onchange` and write same logic.